# Has_many association with specific values: how-to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to build a (toy/learning) RoR app for managing personal boardgame library, but I'm stuck when I try to define a correct data structure.
Basically, a user owns a library with many games. For each game, the user defines a price and a rating.

So I have a simple model for user, with `name:text` attribute and a model for game, with `title:text` attribute.

I also have a `library` model, that references the `user` model, and have a one-to-many relationship with `games`.

Now I'm not sure how to define the attributes `rating` and `price` for the games on the library.

Simple idea is to define `report` as join table from library and games with attributes `rating` and `price`, but I feel this solution so... clumsy.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

No clumsy at all. It is the right solution, indeed.

You need a many-to-many association between `library` and `game` since a library can have many games and a game can be in many libraries.

As you said, create the model `report` referencing both `library` and `game` plus the columns `rating` and `price`, then define the `has_many :through` associations:

```rb
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
  has_many :libraries, through: :reports
end

class Library < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reports
  has_many :games, through: :reports
end
```